# How do I specify the constructor docstring for a Django model?

Tags: python, django

Then I run `pdoc Mymodel` in the python shell, I want the docstring for the constructor of my django model. Where can I specify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `__init__` method.

```
class MyModel(models.Model)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        """My docstring
        """
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```